# The choice of architecture for a cli with a foreground process

Tags: windows, go, daemon

I'm working under cli tool which must communicate with another foreground always running processes. Tool will be used on Windows|MacOS machines. I had a problem with the choice of architecture for it, here are my thoughts:

- single binary, spawn daemon process[es] on start, communicate with signals or via loopback network. There could be lot of headache with daemonization (have no clue how to daemonize windows process), daemon status checks.
- multiple executable files. Drawback - not obvious how cli could find worker process(pid files? process name lookup?), probably deployment issues.

I will be grateful for any advice on the topic of my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407592/named-pipes-in-go-for-both-windows-and-linux

Comment: Bear in mind that Go offers no support for daemonizing a process. Your only option is to background it when it's executed (e.g. on mac/linux `nohup myapp &`).