# Is it possible to run a Golang REST web app on an internal (private) IIS server?

Tags: rest, web-services, go, iis, tomcat7

I would like to create a web service with GoLang that runs either on IIS (7, 8 or 10) or under Tomcat 7.0.  We have multiple environments, each with multiple servers, all being Windows 2008 R2, 2012 or 2016.  All servers are private (10.x).  My goal is to add some REST services to a [COTS product](https://www.microfocus.com/products/solutions-business-manager/#) that uses both IIS and Tomcat.  I'd prefer to avoid gluing nginx or something else onto either server at the risk of impairing the COTS product or having their tech support people not answer the phone.  Again .. the servers are only accessible via corporate VPN and are not public internet-facing.

Which server would offer the easiest path to get something working -- Tomcat or IIS?

Comment: Learn HttpPlatformHandler.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really about Go, but still there exist at least two solutions I can think of:

- Reverse proxying of HTTP requests.

  1. Write a plain Go server serving requests via HTTP.

     Maybe turn it into a proper Windows service using [`golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc).
  2. Deploy it.

     If it's to be hosted on the same machine which runs IIS, then it's fine to make it listen on `localhost` only. Note that it will need a dedicated TCP port to listen on, and you'll need to make it possible for your server to be somehow configurable in this regard.
  3. Set up [reverse proxying in your IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) so that it forwards requests coming to whatever (part of an) URL you want to the Go server.
- Use FastCGI.

  Go supports serving requests over the FastCGI
  protocol [by means of its standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/),
  and [IIS suports FastCGI workers](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/fastcgi-for-iis).

  So it's possible to (re-)write your Go server to use FastCGI
  instead of HTTP and then hook it into IIS via this protocol.

The pros and cons of these solutions—as I view them—are:

- Serving over plain HTTP is more familiar to a developer and
  makes the server more "portable"—in the sense it will be easier to change its deployment scheme if/when you'll need it.
  Right to making it available to the Internet directly.

  Conversely, with FastCGI, you'll always need a FastCGI host as a "middleware".
- There were rumors that HTTP code is more fine-tuned in terms
  of performance than that of FastCGI.

  Still, this only will be of concern for reasonably hard-core loads.
- One possible upside of FastCGI over HTTP is that it can
  be served over pipes rather than TCP. For instance, you might
  get it served over named pipes as it's supported by IIS's FastCGI module and there exists [3rd-party packages for Go implementing support for them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407943/720999)
  (even including one from Microsoft®).

  The upside of this is that pipes are beleived to incur lesser overhead for data transfer (basically it's just shoveling bytes between in-kernel buffers belonging to two processes instead of pushing them through the whole TCP/IP stack), and using pipes frees you from the need of dedicating a TCP port to the Go server.

  Still, I have no personal experience with this kind of setup and its performance trade-offs.

Comment: Thank you for the extended response.  For the HTML approach, (showing my ignorance here) do I need proxying?  The server is isolated from the internet and the domain it's on can only be accessed via VPN.

Comment: Please understand that the proxying is not about security—it's about making "front-end" server (that one which serves all incoming requests) "delegate" some of the incoming requests to some other server. That's how I understood the initial task. If, for some reason, you just got fixated on that you need a web server (be it IIS or nginx) to somehow make a program written in Go serve HTTP requests, then you're simply wrong: a HTTP-serving program written in Go can—and usually is—completely free-standing and self-sufficient.

Comment: That os you just make it somehow configurable (from environment or the registry or a config file or command-line parameters or a combination of some of the above) and run telling it to which address and port to listen on, and then make your site(s) send HTTP requests to it; that's all. You do not need IIS or any other web server to somehow "run your Go code".